# Custom contact has invalid ContactListId on Windows Universal

Tags: contacts, win-universal-app

I am experiencing some strange behaviour in the Windows Universal Contacts API.  Consider the following method:

```
public async Task TestContactStore()
{
    //Fetch store and create custom contact list
    ContactStore localStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AppContactsReadWrite);
    var list = await localStore.CreateContactListAsync("Contact Store Test");

    //Create new contact in custom contact list
    await list.SaveContactAsync(new Contact() { Name = "Test", LastName = "Contact"});

    ContactStore allAccessStore = await ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync(ContactStoreAccessType.AllContactsReadOnly);

    //Print all available contact lists
    Debug.WriteLine("All Contact Lists");
    var contactLists = await allAccessStore.FindContactListsAsync();
    foreach (var contactList in contactLists)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(contactList.DisplayName + ": " + contactList.Id);
    }
    //Print all available contacts
    Debug.WriteLine("All Contacts");
    var contacts = await allAccessStore.FindContactsAsync();
    foreach (var contact in contacts)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(contact.Name + " " + contact.LastName + ": " + contact.ContactListId);
    }
}
```

It creates a contact list for my app (`"Contact Store Test"`). Then it saves a new Contact to this list (`"Test Contact"`). After this it prints all available contact lists and then all contacts.

The output is:

```
All Contact Lists
Hotmail: 24,5,5
Contact Store Test: 24,11,11
All Contacts
Hotmail Contact: 24,5,5
Test Contact: 24,5,5
```

Why does the `Test Contact` show up with the same `ContactListId` as the `Hotmail`-list? In the contacts app on the phone it shows up as belonging to the `Contact Store Test`-list. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now done some further research regarding this behavior. In the latest build 10.0.10512.1000, this behavior has changed. All `ContactListId` return empty string now.

When fetching contacts the way I did in my example above

```
var contactLists = await allAccessStore.FindContactListsAsync();
foreach (var contact in contactLists)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(contactList.DisplayName + ": " + contactList.Id);
}
```

It seems as though the contacts in the list are always aggregated contacts (even if they are not linked in the address book). Aggregated contacts (apparently) always has empty `ContactListId` and `AggregateId`. The `Id`-property always matches the `AggregateId`-property of the corresponding raw contacts.
To get the corresponding contact list id, the raw contacts for that aggregate needs to be fetched:

```
var contactLists = await allAccessStore.FindContactListsAsync();
foreach (var contact in contactLists)
{
    var rawContacts = await allAccessStore.AggregateContactManager.FindRawContactsAsync(aggregateContact);
    foreach (var raw in rawContacts)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(contactList.DisplayName + ": " + contactList.Id);
    }
}
```

This gives expected `ContactListId`.